# Images downloaded with Python are corrupted?

Tags: python, image, urllib2

I try to download images, but they become corrupted for some reason? For example: This is an image I want to get.

[image]

And the result is this

[image]

My test code is:

```
import urllib2

def download_web_image(url):
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    img = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    with open ('test.jpg', 'w') as f: f.write(img)

download_web_image("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_025.jpg")
```

Why is this and how do I fix this?

Comment: You'll likely want to open `test.jpg` in binary mode: `open('test.jpg', 'wb')`

Comment: @WanderNauta Thank you, that fixes it. :)

Comment: Great! I'll write it out as an actual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening 'test.jpg' file in the default (text) mode, which causes Python to use the "correct" newlines on Windows:

> In text mode, the default when reading is to convert platform-specific
>   line endings (\n on Unix, \r\n on Windows) to just \n. When writing in
>   text mode, the default is to convert occurrences of \n back to
>   platform-specific line endings.

Of course, JPEG files are not text files, and 'fixing' the newlines will only corrupt the image. Instead, open the file in binary mode:

```
with open('test.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img)
```

For more details, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).